# Meaning of "platinum sensitivity and primary PFI being repowered as prognostic factors"

Tags: cancer, terminology, clinical-study

Quote from a [clinical trial report](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10147-018-1319-y?wt_mc=Internal.Event.1.SEM.ArticleAuthorOnlineFirst&utm_source=ArticleAuthorOnlineFirst&utm_medium=email&utm_content=AA_en_06082018&ArticleAuthorOnlineFirst_20180723):

> Recurrence eventually affects 70–80% of patients with advanced epithelial ovar-ian cancer [2, 22], with platinum sensitivity and primary PFI **being repowered** as prognostic factors for recurrent epithelial ovarian cancer [22, 23].

What is the meaning of "being repowered"? Does it mean "these factors were considered important predictors in the past, but then the interest waned, and recently there has been renewed interest and research into the role of these factors as prognostic factors"?